# Implementing polymorphism inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method for UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, polymorphism

I have a `genericTableViewController` - `GTBVC` - class which gets segued into by currently two other view controllers each having their own data array that gets passed into this `GTBVC`.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id object = [self.genericArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *textNameOfObject = [[self.genericArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] performSelector:@selector(name)];

#warning - todo: Create a polymorphistic method for each uitableviewcells.

    if([object isMemberOfClass:[OXPersonModel class]]){
        OXFriendTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTableViewCellFriendIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.friendNameLabel.text = textNameOfObject;


        [PKQuickMethods setCornerRadiusForView:cell.friendImageView withCornerRadius:CGRectGetWidth(cell.friendImageView.frame)/2];
        cell.friendImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image"];
        [cell.friendImageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
        return cell;
    }
    else if([object isMemberOfClass:[OXTagPlaceCountModel class]]){
        OXTagTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kTableViewCellTagIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.tagNameLabel.text = textNameOfObject;
        cell.tagPlacesCountLabel.text = [[self.genericArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] performSelector:@selector(totalPlacesCountString)];
        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

So far this method isn't too bad. However, because I wish to make my code scalable for the future - when I expand the program to cater for other cells and product types - I'll need to ensure that it's easy to implement.

Polymorphism comes to mind. I was thinking that each UITableView subclass will need to implement a common method name such as `-[cell updateForModelObject:]` so that in the end the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will only have a couple of lines of code.

But I find myself imagining that I still need to figure out which cells to dequeue based on their identifiers. The cell to dequeue is dependant on which object type is inside the `self.genericArray`.

How can I make the current code inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` polymorphic without using any if statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you're describing can often be implemented using a Protocol. Here's how:

In your GTBVC header, declare a protocol such as:

```
@protocol GTBVCCellConfiguration
   -(void)updateForModelObject:(id)anObject;
@end
```

Then create your UITableViewCell subclasses, conform them to that protocol and have them implement that method. In the subclasses, you can swap out the "id" argument type for the actual data type that you expect.

Since your generic table view controller will handle different kinds of data, you could declare an Enum to specify the various modes that your generic tableview controller could take:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, GenericTableViewMode) {
  case GenericTableViewModePerson,
  case GenericTableViewModePlace
};
```

Then in your GTBVC's header, declare a property for that type:

```
 @property (assign, nonatomic) GenericTableViewMode tableViewMode
```

In the feeder view controllers, import that GTBVC header and implement prepare for segue:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:#yourSegueIdentifierForPerson#]) {
       ((GenericTableViewController *)segue.destinationViewController).mode = GenericTableViewModePerson; 
   } else {
       // check for the next storyboard identifier and set the mode
   }
 }
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath (with a bit of shorthand):

```
-(void)tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: {
   id object = [self.genericArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   UITableViewCell <GTBVCellConfiguration> *cell = nil;

   switch (self.mode) {
     case GenericTableViewModePerson:
         cell = [tableView dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier:@"PERSON" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     case GenericTableViewModePlace:
         cell = [tableView dequeueResuableCellWithIdentifier:@"PLACE" forIndexPath:indexPath];
   }

   [cell updateForModelObject:object];
   return cell;
 }
```

If you wanted to, you could even make a method that returns the correct identifier for the tableview's current mode.

Comment: Hey Woodster. 
1) Could you please elaborate on the `<>` syntax and explain the purpose of it's use in your code snippet please, maybe add some references to concise reading material please.
since  `.. <GTBVCellConfiguration>..` confuses me. 

2) This may be linked to the first question but why are we having all our subclassed `UITableViewCell`s conform to a  `GTBVCCellConfiguration` protocol. What's the purpose of doing so?

Comment: Having your subclasses conform to a protocol is a way to perform a kind of fake multiple inheritance. You define an interface with one or more method signatures (the protocol) and then you have your tableview cells implement those methods.  The syntax of "UITableViewCell <GTBCellConfiguration> *cell" means "A tableview cell that has all the normal tableview cell methods, plus the methods described in this <protocol>."

Comment: 3) You're using switch statements, again this can get quite ugly, its just a glorified if statement block. Anyway we can do without it through polymorphism?

I understand that we need to be able to dequeue the right cell in the table view since we are using a generic table view controller to display a multitude of cells and for the future, but if there's a way to make do without the if/switch blocks then that would be awesome. I had hoped that polymorphism would have helped here, no?

Please see: `http://bit.ly/1vaFfh8`

Comment: To ditch the switch, use a protocol on your model objects too, as another poster said. That protocol would have a method like "-(NSString *)cellIdentifier" and you could call it directly. Protocols, like delegation, are preferred over subclassing in Objective-C because they keep messaging contracts loosely coupled.
Here's the official documentation to Protocols:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: For what it's worth, if you were doing this code in Swift, you could include a function in your Enum that returns the cell identifier for the current enum value. Internally it would be a switch, but that switch would be encapsulated into the enumerated data type.

Comment: Hey woodster, yeah the other poster had a sexy point regarding cellIdentifier. That was a nice touch. Can't believe I overlooked that one.

Comment: While I like this solution, it smacks of the kinds of things one would do in a statically typed language like Java, C#, or even Swift, rather than a dynamic one like ObjC. A protocol to make `updateWithModel:` work is great. Enums and the rest, in this particular case, feel like overkill to me. I think this is a clear case for [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration).

Comment: I chose an enum because it demonstrates patterns we see within UIKit. It also scales well, and lets clang detect scenarios where an older switch isn't updated to handle an case added later. If the OP hadn't asked for scalability, and would only have a couple model types, I wouldn't go with an Enum, but for future scaling, sure. I also prefer not having the workings of the code be based on the names of classes or model objects because of the greater potential for failure once someone starts refactoring, not knowing there's an implicit dependency in the class/model names. But that's just me.

Comment: Am I correct that we can get rid of the switch statement and the enum type altogether by implementing a `cellIdentifier` method too in the protocol? This would prevent us from having to check against the type of object stored in the `self.genericArray` since all the objects stored inside this array would already conform to the same protocol anyway.

Comment: @Woodster can we jump into a quick chat session? I foresee myself having a problem here and there for which I would like to quickly ask you post mini-questions about.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would include a `protocol` also, but rather a protocol you place on your model objects. It could have a method like `-(NSString*)cellIdentifier` that returns a unique identifier for that model class. Then you just dequeue from your table view by getting the model object for that index. Additionally you could define methods on your model protocol that are used by the cell for configuration.

This means you could define any object to conform to this protocol and is now usable with your cell anywhere.

Comment: Whats the difference in using a protocol that all my model objects conform too compared to using a `performSelector:` method with all the model objects conforming a common method name? Wouldn't they both achieve the same thing? I see that all the answers here steer towards all the model objects conforming to a protocol, any reason for this?

Comment: Using performSelector is unsafe because the system has no information about the method being dispatched. It is better to be explicit about the intention as much as possible. Also, why would you bother with performSelector if you are going to put the method name on all of the headers?

Comment: You say that `Additionally you could define methods on your model protocol that are used by the cell for configuration.` could you elaborate on this?
From what I understand, are you saying that I should `import` the custom data model into its associated subclassed tableview cells so that I can then have a method for configurating the cell with a method like: `[cell updateForModelObject:]`? Shouldn't the views and models be kept seperate?

Comment: What that means is that your protocol require as many methods on a conforming class as you want. So, as an example, say your cells need to display two different lines of information, your protocol could define three total methods: `-(NSString*)cellIdentifier`, `-(NSString*)cellLine1`, and `-(NSString*)cellLine2`. Then your cell configuration method is defined as `-(void)configureForObject:(id<PROTOCOLNAME>)obj`. In that method you would only need to call those protocol methods and would work for any conforming object.

Comment: but then how do you differentiate which objects is passed into the `configureForObject` parameter to then be able to update the cell accordingly, since different subclassed cells have different properties?

Comment: That is the point of implementing those protocol methods on the model classes. Within those implementations you can return whatever would make sense for that model class. I would suggest reading the documentation linked by Woodster in one of his comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use [convention over configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) and name your cell identifiers in a way determined by the type of the model, e.g.,

```
NSString *modelClassName = NSStringFromClass(model.class);
NSString *modelCellClassIdentifier = [modelClassName stringByAppendingString:@"TableViewCellIdentifier"];
UITableViewCell<ModelUpdatable> *cell = [tableView dequeuReusableCellWithIdentifier:modelCellClassIdentifier];
[cell updateWithModel:model];
```

Thus, if your model is called `Person`, your cell's identifier would be `PersonTableViewCellIdentifier`. (And I would recommend calling your cell `PersonTableViewCell`.)

I use this technique so often I have a macro to declare the identifiers, which I'm going to try to reproduce from memory, so treat it as pseudocode:

```
PRODeclareCellIdentifier(model) extern NSString *const model##TableViewCellIdentifier
PRODefineCellIdentifier(model) NSString *const model##TableViewCellIdentifier = @#model##TableViewCellIdentifier
```

In your cell's header you'd say `PRODeclareCellIdentifier(Person)`. And in its implementation you'd say `PRODefineCellIdentifier(Person)`. I use macros sparingly, but they can be very, very useful for boilerplate like this.

Comment: Hi Gregory. This seems fragile because its dependant on the naming convention being there. Also, my cells are subclassed of UITableViewCell - so they have their own class name having their own unique properties.  UITableViewCell does not conform to the `updateWithModel` method.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. :) Convention over configuration is well known and widely used. Many, many modern application frameworks rely on it, such as Ruby on Rails. The `updateWithModel` thing isn't hard to solve. After all, ObjC is a dynamic language.

Comment: I added a protocol so that you can call `updateWithModel:` in perfect type safety. Some of the other answers also show how to do this.

Comment: lol... My comments were for your original answer. Now, you've just edited your code, so my points no longer stand valid ;)

Comment: No worries. :) Do what seems best to you. All of these will work, but the other ones seem a bit verbose to me, and more suited to statically typed languages like C#, Java, or Swift, than to a dynamically typed one like ObjC.